# openpyxl error : "TypeError: <class 'openpyxl.packaging.custom.StringProperty'>.name should be <class 'str'> but value is <class 'NoneType'>"

Tags: python, openpyxl

The following error occurred while I was loading an Excel file with Python.

The sheet names are entered identically.

I was planning to import the file and use the data inside.
However, an error occurred when loading the file, so you cannot proceed.

part of my code:

```
user_data = xl.load_workbook(filename="통합 문서1.xlsx", data_only=True) 
book_data = xl.load_workbook(filename="booklist.xlsx", data_only=True) 
load_bl = book_data["sheet 1"] 
load_ws = user_data["Sheet1"] 
print(load_ws.cell(1, 1).value) 
print(load_bl.cell(3, 4).value)
```

and the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\W10P\Desktop\Folder 1\Privacy\Privacy\library.py", line 173, in <module>
    book_data = xl.load_workbook(filename="booklist.xlsx", data_only=True)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\W10P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\W10P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 295, in read
    self.read_custom()
  File "C:\Users\W10P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 182, in read_custom
    self.wb.custom_doc_props = CustomPropertyList.from_tree(src)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\W10P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\custom.py", line 220, in from_tree
    new_prop = typ(name=prop.name, value=value)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\W10P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\custom.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.name = name
    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\W10P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 46, in __set__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: <class 'openpyxl.packaging.custom.StringProperty'>.name should be <class 'str'> but value is <class 'NoneType'>
```

First line of excel file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApwTw.png)

The same goes for the rest of the lines.

I'm curious why this error appears. I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you have `None` in some place that a string is expected. Oh, and it would help if you provided a [mcve]! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: There appears to be nothing inherently wrong with the code segment provided so check booklist.xlsx or try another xlsx file in its place. From the line numbering in the traceback it looks like the Openpyxl release is not the latest. Always good idea to update to the latest unless there is a specific reason not to.